swift conversion from TimeInterval to Int
There is something wrong with my method, instead of printing me 05-07-2024 it prints me 07-07-2024
TimeInterval = 1720189102.0
print: Optional((year: Optional(2024), month: Optional(7), day: Optional(7)))
https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php
extension TimeInterval {
    
   func dateTimestampDividedInt(date: TimeInterval) -> (year: Int?, month: Int?, day: Int?) {
        
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        let dateConv = Date()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy"
        let year = dateFormatter.string(from: dateConv)
        let yearInt = Int(year)
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM"
        let month = dateFormatter.string(from: dateConv)
        let monthInt = Int(month)
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd"
        let day = dateFormatter.string(from: dateConv)
        let dayInt = Int(day)
        
        return (yearInt, monthInt, dayInt)
    }

}

What should a correct func look like?

The correct function should use calendars components. That means return value isn't even needed to be optional. And it automatically converts it to Int. And its shorter. And it fixes the problem.
extension TimeInterval {
    static func dateTimestampDividedInt(date: TimeInterval) -> (year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: date)
        
        let day = calendar.component(.day, from: date)
        let month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
        let year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)
        
        return (year, month, day)
    }
}


This is indeed the correct answer. Simpler, cleaner, and safer than the OPs approach. (Voted)
